# OpenXML PowerTools HtmlConverter adding unnesssary table borders

Tags: c#, html, itext, openxml-sdk, productivity-power-tools

I am working on a project where I have to convert a DOCX -> PDF as generic as possible and automated. We decided to go with OpenXML for the find and replace of fields that need updating and the HtmlConverter that is listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628051%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as an extension to the OpenXML SDK. WE are then using iTextSharp to convert the HTML document to a PDF. The issue I am currently having is that whenever I create a borderless table in Word, when I use the HTMLConverter class, it is putting borders around ALL the tables. I made sure that the Word documents table is definitely borderless and not just a white border or something (this document was provided by the customer, so I wanted to make sure.

Does anyone know how I can either intercept the converter in some override or set some sort of setting for the converter to not put borders around every table?

Comment: Afaik there is a little test harness tool that ships with SDK that will let you pull in any document and see the underlying markup it generates. I too did this once and when you use their automated tools like the converter it tends to add more markup than necessary. If you want total control its often easier to do it yourself. Also, good idea with the iTextSharp, we used Word Automation to save as PDF which the latest PIAs supported, but Office on the server was a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @kd7. This is on a server and via web, but needs to be automated. WE too tried the automation and had issues with it. It is definetly a bad idea as you said. This tool you are talking about. Is it the Open XML SD Productivity Tool? Or something else?